# Qual o símbolo para produto direto?

Tags: latex

qual o símbolo para produto direto, como mostra o exemplo?
Ex.: `(1,2,3,4)*(1,2,3,4) = (1, 4, 9, 16)`

Comment: Tem um site bem legal em que você desenha o símbolo e ele dá o nome pra você: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/

Comment: @wagnerJorge, não conhecia essa definição de produto directo; podes confirmar que o resultado pretendido é mesmo esse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não consigo comentar, então, vou postar aqui mesmo.

Em modo texto, a símbolo pro produto cartesiano (ou produto direto) no LaTeX é

```html
\texttimes
```

Refira-se a [este link](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)

Se você conseguir ler em inglês, eu recomendo a comunidade do [StackExchange para Matemática](https://math.stackexchange.com/)